# Injecting services into Entities: check if an image file exists

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine-orm, amazon-s3

I'm using PHP and the Doctrine ORM and here's the deal: I have a product table with an image field and I want an event to check if an image exists in my assets cloud storage (Amazon S3). If the file exists then all is well but if it does not I would like to return the file-path of a  placeholder image.  Now the method that perform the check for the existence of the image resides in my S3Service class.

Is there a way for me to tie an event to the entity such that every time I call something like:

```
$product = $this->em->getRepository('Entities\Product')
                ->findBy(['id' => $productId]);
echo $product->getImagePath();
```

I would be able to get the default image if the file is non existent (by calling the method in S3Service of course). Now I know you shouldn't inject services into entities but it would be much cleaner for the rest of my code if I can abstract this part with my entity. That's why I'm looking at an event driven kind of solution. I have looked at the life cycle events of doctrine entities but I don't know if there's an event which executes as soon as the entity is retrieved.

Question is: What event should I be looking at or should I be looking at another solution altogether?

Comment: The postLoad event (http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#postload) might work for you though checking cloud storage every time an image is loaded seems strange.

Comment: You really think so? I initially thought it works conveniently in my favor. I've been thinking this day about it from a performance perspective and it does feel kinda heavy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to injecting services into entities (eg. in method parameters). IMO you should create service which operates on images and in specific methods gets entity as parameter. As Kris Wallsmith said on SymfonyCon - Models are thin layers between application and persistent (db) layer. They shouldn't contains lot of logic.